# Similiar to WBS, can sharepoint percentage auto calculate percentages?

Tags: tasks, task-list, ms-project, timeline, scheduled-tasks

For instance, if I have one main task, with 5 subtasks under it....and each of those 5 subtasks has a percent complete filled out.....

I then want the main task to auto-calculate a total percentage complete like it does in a project....is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately**, it's not possible

The **roll-up** feature that used to auto calculate the overall `%Complete` is **not** available in the `SharePoint Tasks list`.

It's only available in the `Project Schedule` in Project Server & Microsoft Project.